# $X$=number of tosses. $p$ is picked randomly from $(\frac{1}{3},1)$. A coin with probability $p$ for heads is tossed until the first $H$ What is E(X)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$=number of tosses. $p$ is picked randomly from $(\frac{1}{3},1)$. A coin with probability $p$ for heads is tossed until the first H. What is $E(X)$?

Now I understand I need to use the law of total expected, but I'm not sure how to use it exactly.

I know that

$$E[X]= E[E[X|Y=p]]$$

I know that $X$ is distributed geometrically with probably $p$ for heads, and that Y is distributed uniformly on $[ \frac{1}{3},1]$.

$$E[Y]= \frac{2}{3}, \quad 
E[X\mid Y=p]=\frac1p$$

What are the steps required to use the equation listed above?

I am more interested in learning how to use the formula, rather than just a clear cut answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"A coin with probability p for heads is tossed again and again"*? What is the stopping condition?

Comment: @ClementC. sorry, character restriction is stressful. Tossed until first heads.

Comment: There's no character restriction in the body of the question. The title is way too long; it should be a short summary of the question; and the body is still missing the stopping condition.

Comment: Conditioned on $p$, you have a [geometric random variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). The mean of such a random variable is $\frac{1}{p}$, so $\mathbb{E}[X\mid p]=\frac{1}{p}$... now, since $p$ itself is uniform in $(1/3,1)$, what is $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid p]]$?

Comment: @ClementC. which expected value do I work on first? The inner one or outer one?

Comment: The inner one. It's also directly in the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is geometrically distributed, $E[X \mid Y=p] = \frac 1p$ and $E[Y] = \frac{2}{3}$. Hence $$E[X] = E\big[E[X\mid Y = p]\big]$$ Implying that, $$E[X] = E\bigg[\frac{1}{p}\bigg]$$ and, 
$$E\big[g(p)\big] = \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^1 g(p)f(p)dp$$ where,  $f(p)$ is the p.d.f of the R.V(uniform distribution in this case) and $g(p) = \frac{1}{p}$. Therefore, $$E\bigg[\frac{1}{p}\bigg] = \int_\frac{1}{3}^1 \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{p}dp = \frac{3}{2}\log3$$